# Minimum required ancestor-descendant relationship of n nodes to build a binary tree out of

Tags: algorithms, binary-trees

I have an algorithmic question. Suppose there is a ground truth binary tree of N nodes and there is an oracle which answers queries of the form: given any user specified pair of nodes a and b, do a and b have a ancestor-descendant relationship and if yes, which of them is the direct ancestor of the other?". Now assuming that the oracle is always correct, build an algorithm that constructs the correct/ground truth binary tree of N nodes with the (asymptotically) smallest number of queries from the oracle?

Comment: @InuyashaYagami The assumption is that the ground truth is a binary tree of the N input nodes.

Comment: The oracle answers (parent, child) relationship or (ancestor, descendant) relationship?

Comment: @InuyashaYagami Both, because the oracle gives the ground truth relationship. Suppose there is a ground truth binary tree of N nodes now we don't know the relation of these nodes we can ask the oracle what is the relation of the node a and b and it tells you. Now we are interested in building the ground truth with minimum number of queries.

Comment: The tree can consist of a path of $m$ vertices, with each vertex having the next vertex in the path as its right child and some dummy vertex as its left child. (So $N = 2m-1$ vertices overall.) Determining the correct order of vertices in the path is equivalent to sorting a list of numbers, with the oracle behaving as a comparator for these vertices, so the comparison-based sort lower bound of $\Omega(N \log N)$ queries applies.

Comment: @j_random_hacker, I see. Can you come up with an algorithm to build the tree?

Comment: Seems not possible to distinguish between left and right subtrees of a node.

Comment: @HendrikJan, can you please elaborate more?

Comment: @j_random_hacker, you have very good point the oracle behaving as comparator for these nodes, do you think we can use the notion of "binary search tree" data structure to insert new node? The insertion is $O(logN)$ so in total it would be $O(N log N)$ and at the end the data structure would be the final tree, right?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/142077/755, https://stackoverflow.com/q/68264299/781723.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: @Alex Are you familiar with adversarial lower bound proofs? If so, you can prove that any algorithm must make $\Omega(n^{2})$ queries to the oracle. I will write an answer when I get some time.

Comment: @InuyashaYagami, no I'm not but I'll check it for sure now. Thank you.

Comment: @Alex What I mean is: is the binary tree assumed to be a binary search tree?

Comment: @HendrikJan, well there is no such an assumption in the question but my feeling is that it can be modeled with binary search tree.